# Creating a matrix layout in SAPUI5, Error "Expected identifier, string or number"

Tags: sapui5

```
var oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({
        id :"matrix11",
    layoutFixed : false
    });

var oImage1 = new sap.ui.commons.Image({
    src :  "../Mushirul/images/cancel.png",
    alt : "alternative text for image"
    });

var oImage2 = new sap.ui.commons.Image({
    src : "../Mushirul/images/cancel.png",
    alt : "alternative text for image"
    });

oLayout.createRow( oImage1, oImage2 );  

var oImage3 = new sap.ui.commons.Image({
    src : "http://www.sap.com/global/images/SAPLogo.gif",
    alt : "alternative text for image"
    });

var oImage4 = new sap.ui.commons.Image({
    src : "http://www.sap.com/global/images/SAPLogo.gif",
    alt : "alternative text for image"
    });

oLayout.createRow( oImage3, oImage4 );
```

Comment: In which line of the code snippet above does the error occur?

Comment: @line 2
id="matrix11"  it is asking me to provide stirng or number as id...

Comment: your code works fine. see here: http://jsbin.com/openui5-hello-world/423/edit?html,output